# C++ 11 Dynamic Array Partial List Initialization (Bug or Misunderstanding)?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, new-operator

I have the following C++ 11 code:

```
int *ipa = new int[5]{1, 2, 3};
```

I thought I understood that elements 3 and 4 were supposed to be value (0 in this case) initialized. In Visual C++ 2013, that is happening. In Mingw 4.8.1 it is not; they are being default initialized (that is, uninitialized).

My question is, is this a known compiler (GCC or MingW) bug? I've searched through all the bug lists (and Googled) in vain. Or, have I somehow misunderstood what is supposed to happen?

Comment: [Looks like this was fixed for the 4.9 release series](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/29db8ce2fee8ed7d).

Comment: More specifically: [4.8.1 has the bug](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/YaahoDQESVBxFfyp), [4.8.2 does not](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/0mw4m8fhvkRYqsK3). So [it must be one of these bugs?](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?bug_status=RESOLVED&list_id=113864&resolution=FIXED&target_milestone=4.8.2).

Comment: Casey - thank you. That was exactly the information I needed.

Answer (score 1):

First off, if you suspect there is a bug, there's no harm in reporting it. Here's a link to the [GCC bugzilla](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/) and their [bug reporting instructions](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/). At the very least, you need to provide a test case and the operating system and version of your compiler. There's very little purpose to reporting it to SO first, since you can read [all about initialization here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization).<sup>1</sup>

---

The correct behavior is that the remaining elements are initialized to 0. Quoting the C++11 draft standard:

> §5.3.4/15 A *new-expression* that creates an object of type T
>   initializes that object as follows: [...]
>
> - Otherwise, the *new-initializer* is interpreted according to the initialization rules of 8.5 for direct-initialization.
>
> §8.5.4/3 List-initialization of an object or reference of type `T` is
>   defined as follows: [...]
>
> - Otherwise, if `T` is an aggregate, aggregate initialization is performed (8.5.1).
>
> [...]
>
> - Otherwise, if the initializer list has no elements, the object is value-initialized.
>
> §8.5.1/7 If there are fewer *initializer-clauses* in the list than
>   there are members in the aggregate, then each member not explicitly
>   initialized shall be initialized from an empty initializer list
>   (8.5.4).
>
> §8.5/5 To *zero-initialize* an object or reference of type `T` means:
>
> - if `T` is a scalar type (3.9), the object is set to the value 0 (zero), taken as an integral constant expression, converted to
>     T;<sup>103</sup> [...]
>
> §8.5/7 To *value-initialize* an object of type `T` means: [...]
>
> - if `T` is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;
> - otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.

<sup>1 I've started a meta thread called [Do we need a canonical question about C++ initialization?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286640/do-we-need-a-canonical-question-about-c-initialization) to address the lack of prior research in initialization questions.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The compiler will initialize the 3 and 4 element be 0.

in c++ 11 this expression is be supported.

So that, you can initialize the array (int or char ...) like : `int a[10] = {0};`